# Explaining being fired from a job that was never a good fit

Tags: termination

Backstory: My husband got a job that moved us out of state, and necessitated me leaving a "corporate" company  I had been with for almost 11years. I worked with a recruiter to find a position in my new state of residence. Within hours of the recruiter sending out my resume, I had a hit from a small business that was very excited about my skills. Long story short, I was hired into a position that was far below my skill set,because that is what they needed filled inmediately. I was told it was temporary because they knew I was over qualified for it and my role would change in the near future. I was given very minimal training, and it was off to the races. My primary role never changed in spite of what I was promised, but my responsibilities multiplied. I was buried- any time I tried to ask a question, the boss was too busy, or would forget. Priorities changed by the day, but we're rarely communicated effectively if at all. I was written up for not performing job duties that I thought were shared responsibilities, but in fact were my "priorities" to spite never having been told that they were.

One day, I was "awesome" the next day I was being threatened with being fired. My boss would lose her mind and scream at me, and I could do nothing more than take it.

Today, after several more threats, I was let go. Honestly, it's a relief, and since I had already been job searching (and seriously considered walking out on several occasions) I almost feel like it was mutual- I think I actually said thank you...

I feel confident that my skills will get me an interview, but I'm not sure how to frame my termination from a job that I was over qualified for, working for a crazy person.

Answer (score 9):

Simple explanations are best: it wasn't a good fit.

If they ask you to elaborate: they made some representations to you about the work, and these representations did not pan out. You were operating way below your skill level and they were thoroughly disorganized and direction-less. Your mistake was taking the first offer that came along, and you're not repeating this mistake if you can help it - Live and learn.

Comment: Correct. Just phrase it neutrally, so leave out the 'crazy person' ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen "disorganized" and "direction-less" are specific enough to indicate why anybody who looks rational wouldn't want to work there :)